# Is there any YQL query to get top gainers in Yahoo Financial Public API?

Tags: yahoo, yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I tried to get top 5 gainers from YQL.
there is only Yahoo Financial API with specific symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last , I found there is no solution. The only way I did was to scrap data from yahoo finance site.